# Eclipse - @SuppressWarnings("javadoc") does not work

Tags: eclipse, warnings, javadoc, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have my Eclipse configured to show warnings on missing javadoc comments and tags for public elements. That comes very usefull for me in order to keep my code well documented.

But sometimes I have a class, where I have several constants describing for example states of DFA or something.. theres no need to document theese constant, because they are self-explaining..

So I added annotation **@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")** to the class and here's my point - Eclipse does not concider the annotation and still shows warnings on missing javadocs..

**@SuppressWarnings("all")** does the job, but that has side effects, which are not desired ;-)

Are you experiencing the same issue? Is this a bug or do I only have something missconfigured? Is there any workaround? Or is this corrected in newer versions?

PS: I'm using
Version: 3.3.2
Build id: M20080221-1800

Comment: I have the same issue on version 3.4.1 (M20080911-1700)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=179566), which is still open.

Comment: Well it lokks like the point of the bug is that they want to suppress all warnings by using @SuppressWarnings(""), but the compiler keeps showing javadoc warnings.. this can be done using @SuppressWarnings("all"). Second thing is that the bug is already open for more than 2 years :/

Comment: They have finally made a fix released for 3.7M6 - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=179566

Answer (score 2):

At the end of [this page](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-suppress_warnings.htm) you will find all SuppressWarning options which are handled in Eclipse. Unfortunately currently there is no support for suppressing just javadoc warnings. The bug Andrew mentioned is really a feature request for adding this but it seems to have low priority (you can vote for this bug to show Eclipse developers the importance of this feature for you).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried "allJavadoc" ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that - I've tried that, but Eclipse does not accept this.. It shows warning "Unhandled warning token allJavadoc" - so now I have even one more warning :-D