# Eclipse: suppressing warnings for missing Javadoc tag on RemoteException

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, javadoc

I have Eclipse set up to yield warnings about missing Javadoc tags. However, I would like to suppress warnings for missing `@throws RemoteException` tags for my RMI interfaces, as these are implied by `extends Remote` in my interface declaration.

Is there a way to do this via `@SuppressWarnings` (I'm not that familiar with the syntax) or some other setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")` is the answer, but it does not work in eclipse 3.6. It is fixed for eclipse 3.7.

see here: [Eclipse - @SuppressWarnings("javadoc") does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951062/eclipse-suppresswarningsjavadoc-does-not-work)

and here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=179566

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse - @SuppressWarnings("javadoc") does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951062/eclipse-suppresswarningsjavadoc-does-not-work)

This seems to discuss the issue you're running into. I just checked the bug listed in the answers, it looks like this is going to be added in Eclipse 3.7.